# Magento - Print more than one packing slip at a time

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am currently attempting to print packing slips for all the checked orders in the Sales -> Orders view of the Admin section of Magento.

Every time I select "Print Packingslips" from the Actions Dropdown and click submit, it only returns a single pdf with a single page in it...

Is there anyway to print more than one Packing slip at a time?

Any input is greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Admin panel, select Sales > Shipments . Tick all required packing checkboxes and then press print. they must be first created in the order but for batch printing purposes, printing from shipments is the way to go.